# 評判重視で取れるときは取るって感じで meaning?

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm struggling with understanding how to parse this sentence into a coherent whole:

> そこは評判重視{ひょうばんじゅうし}で取れるときは取るって感じで.

In the context of someone discussing the potential pitfall of a business idea, am I mistaken I believing "評判重視" would be something like "an emphasis on (the business') reputation, and "取れるときは取るって" might be "taking it when you get it"?

I imagine this is a bit odd for those not familiar with the game, but basically it involves someone remarking on how a character who isn't visible to normal people would have trouble running a pet consultation service due to that and getting strays looking for advice. Here's the panel with the line I'm struggling with:

[image]

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand this without context since it's not clear what the object of toru is.

Comment: I added more context and an image of the line in hopes that would clarify things!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the context so these are my guess:

「デゼルが相談に乗ってお代は飼い主からいただくってワケ！」＝ Dezel can give advice and the owner would pay us!

「野良犬だっているでしょ」＝ There would be some stray dogs (to come for a consultation).

「そこは評判重視で取れる時は取るって感じで！」＝ In that case we're more interested in the reputation (we don't care if we can't make money), and will charge when it's possible!

Answer (score 5):

I think you understand 評判重視 correctly. This 取る means お客から金を取る(受け取る), so 取れるときは取る in this context is translated as "to receive money (as much as possible) when we can get it (from customers)".

Comment: That makes much more sense. Thank you!